# Having issues with my FastAPI endpoints unable to access them

Tags: python, fastapi

I am working on a model to predict cancer severity. I have implemented FastAPI to convert the model into an API. However, I cannot access the API, and my terminal is not displaying any error messages. When I access http://127.0.0.1:8000/ I get "details not found" but http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs takes me to the Swagger UI with no endpoints to test

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, Depends
from BaseModel import Cancer_Severity
import pickle
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from fastapi.security import HTTPBasic, HTTPBasicCredentials


app = FastAPI()
security = HTTPBasic()

# Load the trained model
pickle_in = open("new_mammo_model.pkl", "rb")
classifier = pickle.load(pickle_in)

@app.get("/")
def index():
    return {"message": "Welcome to Cancer Severity Prediction"}

@app.get("/Welcome")
def get_name(name: str):
    return {"Welcome to Cancer Severity Prediction": name}

@app.post("/predict")
def predict(data: Cancer_Severity, credentials: HTTPBasicCredentials = Depends(security)):
    data = data.dict()
    
    # Validate input
    age = data['Age']
    shape = data['Shape']
    margin = data['Margin']
    density = data['Density']

    if not 0 <= age <= 100:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Age should be between 0 and 100")

    if shape not in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Shape should be between 1 and 5")

    if margin not in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Margin should be between 1 and 5")

    if density not in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Density should be between 1 and 5")

    # Basic Authentication
    correct_username = "admin"
    correct_password = "password"
    if credentials.username != correct_username or credentials.password != correct_password:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Incorrect username or password")

    # Make prediction
    prediction = classifier.predict([[age, shape, margin, density]])

    if prediction == 0:
        return {"Severity": "Benign"}
    else:
        return {"Severity": "Malignant"}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)
```

I have ran the uvicorn server on my terminal, it shows no error; I am actually expecting parameters to test the ENDPOINT to make sure it is working

Comment: What are we supposed to see in the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By opening http://127.0.0.1:8000/, you will see the message you have returned under the "/" endpoint.

To see the docs, visit http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs.

FastAPI has excellent documentation, which you can find [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/#interactive-api-docs)

Comment: When I access http://127.0.0.1:8000/ I get "details not found" but http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs takes me to the Swagger UI with no endpoints to test

Comment: Did you try http://localhost:8000/ ?

Comment: I did but it is showing blank endpoints

Comment: I commented out lines 4-6, 11, and 12 and it works fine for me!

Comment: Tried it now and it is working. Thank you